# Recording SurfaceView in Android

Tags: android, video-recording, android-video-player, android-video-record

I'm working on a video application where I need to open the front camera and show a the camera preview in the screen. At the same time, I need to apply some effects (like words on the screen) and record all together in order to form a final `.mp4` where the video and the effects are both displayed.

I'm trying to understand what would be the correct approach to do this. I don't know if I should capture the whole screen, or to capture the information coming from the `SurfaceView` and later draw the effects on it.

I've been reading something about `RecordableSurfaceView`.
Would you recommend me to use this library or should I change the approach?

Comment: If you don't want to use external libraries, you can use `TextureView`, which is slower, but can be captured like any other view.

Comment: And If I want to use them? Could OpenGL be a good option?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app where I stream live video with Surfaceview. After a lot of research, I couldn't find how to save the video on surfaceview. Then I tried the HBRecorder library and was successful.

I set the video encoder to H264. You can change a lot of features like that. I'm put the github link below. I hope that helps.

[HBRecorder for screen recording](https://github.com/HBiSoft/HBRecorder)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For those who are searching for some kind of record like Instagram (Instastories with real time filters) I found out CameraView. Just in case you want to take a look :) Btw thank you for your answer